How to generate Ton wallet using JavaScript
I have problem to create Ton wallet with tonweb library.
I tried to generate private key first and get publickey from private key , then get address wallet from public key.
But the Address wallet is not depended on Private key!
const TonWeb = require("tonweb");
const nacl = require("tweetnacl");

(async () => {
  const tonwebInstance = new TonWeb();

  // Generate a random 32-byte private key
  const privateKey = nacl.randomBytes(32);
  const privateKeyHex = Buffer.from(privateKey).toString("hex");

  // Create a key pair from the private key
  const keyPair = nacl.sign.keyPair.fromSeed(privateKey);

  // Extract the public key from the key pair
  const publicKey = keyPair.publicKey;
  const publicKeyHex = Buffer.from(publicKey).toString("hex");

  // Create a wallet using the public key as Uint8Array
  const wallet = tonwebInstance.wallet.create({
    publicKey: publicKey,
  });

  // Get the wallet address
  const walletAddress = (await wallet.getAddress()).toString(true, true, true);

  console.log("Private key (hex):", privateKeyHex);
  console.log("Public key (hex):", publicKeyHex);
  console.log("Wallet address:", walletAddress);
})();


According to the tweetnacl documentation, using the fromSeed function is not recommended. I've changed your code to simply use the recommended nacl.sign.keyPair() function and it works as desired:
const TonWeb = require("tonweb");
const nacl = require("tweetnacl");

(async () => {
  const tonwebInstance = new TonWeb();

  // Create a key pair
  const keyPair = nacl.sign.keyPair();

  // Extract the public key from the key pair
  const publicKey = keyPair.publicKey;
  const publicKeyHex = Buffer.from(publicKey).toString("hex");

  // Extract the private key from the key pair
  const privateKey = keyPair.secretKey;
  const privateKeyHex = Buffer.from(privateKey).toString("hex");

  // Create a wallet using the public key as Uint8Array
  const wallet = tonwebInstance.wallet.create({publicKey});

  // Get the wallet address
  const walletAddress = (await wallet.getAddress()).toString(true, true, true);

  console.log("Wallet address:", walletAddress);
  console.log("Public key (hex):", publicKeyHex);
  console.log("Private key (hex):", privateKeyHex);
})();

The output is a 64-byte private key, as opposed to the previous implementation of a 32-byte private key.

But I need 64 characters long Private key and this code generate 128 characters long

Why? I can't think of any legitimate reason for that requirement.

This is the result:
Wallet address: EQCyhLpANiniUgvy1ICNxrhFdWXfnnJMl_lAmt5HytTqNg4n
Public key (hex): 17667ec2fc7ae44d7f899840ecb363f3a82f8746d48e64873ce0f1134302120a
Private key (hex): 047b636e9ae66f67fcbe19dd208e0d0d308456cf45d878ba0d240f40f3bd674517667ec2fc7ae44d7f899840ecb363f3a82f8746d48e64873ce0f1134302120a

Yes, what about it?

This private key is 128 characters long, and I can't use it in another app like Trust wallet

The secretKey from keyPair() is NOT an absolute privateKey. It is the combination of seed + publicKey. If you want to extract 32-byte of privateKey, You need to slice the seed (first 32 bytes of secretKey). Check my answer.

@Aaron Meese's answer is correct.
But I am adding this since you asked specifically that you need 32-byte of privateKey. By default, nacl.sign.keyPair() generates 64-byte of Combined Private Key.

Combined Private Key (64-byte) = Seed (32-byte) + Public Key (32-byte)

In case, you REALLY want to stick with 32-byte of privateKey, You have to slice it from the Combined Private Key.
const combinedPrivateKey = keyPair.secretKey; // Seed + Public Key

// Sling first 32 bytes which is Seed that can be used as Private Key
const privateKey = combinedPrivateKey.slice(0, 32);
const privateKeyHex = Buffer.from(privateKey).toString("hex");


You can also try this to generate with mnemonic
const createWallet = async () => {
    const tonweb = new TonWeb();
    const words = await generateMnemonic();
    const seed = await mnemonicToSeed(words);
    const keyPair = TonWeb.utils.nacl.sign.keyPair.fromSeed(seed);
    console.log(TonWeb.utils.bytesToHex(keyPair.secretKey));

    const WalletClass = tonweb.wallet.all.v3R2;
    const wallet = new WalletClass(tonweb.provider, {
        publicKey: keyPair.publicKey
    });
    const address = await wallet.getAddress();
    console.log(address.toString(true, true, false)); // print address in format to display in UI
}

